# When/where to set up new state in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my App.js file I fetch the needed data and assign the value to different store states.

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.props.fetchUser();
        this.props.fetchBeers();


    }
```

Now in a child component, I try to fetch the data from the store. But according to my console.logs the store states that I need arn't immediately available. It takes around 4 console.logs to able see the data.

Now I use some checks before setting some new local states. I tried to set my local states in the DidMountComponent() function. it does not work, bcz the needed data isn't available directly. So I set the set local states function in my Render()

```
if(this.props.beers.beer.length>0 && this.state.beerArrayLoaded===false){
        this.setState({beerArrayLoaded:true});
        this.setState({BeerArray:this.props.beers.beer});

    }
```

I wonder if there is a more proper way to set up new state after the data from the store is available?

Comment: Do not set state in render. So, you have a global store via Redux, also you need local state in your Child component? If this state coming from Redux store, why don't use it directly?

Comment: I see, because I like to transform the fetched data and store in a local state.

Comment: First of all, do your fetch part in componentDidMount on your App. You are setting your store through Redux right? How do you render your Child component? It will be better to see your components, otherwise helping will be harder.

Comment: @devserkan I see where my mistakes is. I didn't fetch the right data in my child component.